# Adjusted incidence rate using poisson regression

Tags: r, poisson

I have a data set showing the number of events in two groups, the first with a certain disease and the other one are the comparators. Events is the number of events during follow-up. PY is person-years. Number is the total number of participants at start of follow-up.

```
        Group   Sex Number Events        PY
1     Disease women    721     95  4502.817
2     Disease   men    309     39  1124.824
3 Comparators women   3894    289 25169.310
4 Comparators   men   1614    109  6421.807
```

I would like to estimate sex-adjusted incidence rates using Poisson regression with CI. The desired outcome is:
The sex-adjusted incidence rate in the "Disease" group is xx per PYs
The sex-adjusted incidence rate in the "Comparators" group is xx per PYs

Thanks in advance!

Should I use the glm function? Appreciate any help